# Is the checkerboard background as seen in UIDocumentInteractioController predefined in iOS?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

I have implemented a scrollview which uses a `CATiledLayer`. In `UIDocumentInteractionController` the view shows some kind of checkerboard background while loading its contents. I wonder if there is something similar to `UIColor.ScrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor` to get this checkerboard? Or do I have to use my own image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's none in the IOS documentation, unfortunately. Apple uses their custom backgrounds on a lot of apps, and in general you just need to create it and load it with the `UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromBundle("image"))` command.

Comment: Oh well, I'll use my own then. THx.